# C++ Directx 11 rendering issue

Tags: c++, model, import, directx-11

I have developed an .obj importer, but there is a small little problem:

[image: A camper, which is pretty screwed up...]

Now, I've tried to reverse the indices, and also reverse the normals. But none of them worked, reversing the normals went incredible wrong.

Do you guys have any suggestions of what might be wrong, what can i do?

Thank You

PS. The expected output, ignore the colors:

[image]

Comment: What is the finished model actually supposed to look like?

Comment: IMO, you would probably find it far easier and more productive to use something like assimp to import models etc, unless is for learning of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be coming from 3 different problems:
1/Face culling, try to create a rasterizer with D3D11_CULL_MODE to None, Front and Back and check if it makes a difference, also setting as wireframe might help for debugging.

2/Depth buffer might not be set properly

3/Problem with your importer, but would need to see the code for more help.

Comment: This indeed looks like culling is set to the wrong turning order - look closely at the wheels and you'll see that only their back faces are rendered and shaded (which is why they look like some optical illusion).